# About using Python PyQt5 in pycharm

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried running PyQt5 in pycharm which works initially as i can see an window popping up with a title fixed to it

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget, QGridLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Who wants to be a programmer?")
window.setFixedWidth(1000)




window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

if I run this code then a window appears with a title!
But if I try to work on it more and run the code, a window appears on the taskbar but I cannot see or open it!

Comment: What do you mean with "But if I try to work on it more and run the code"?

Answer (score -1):

Try sub-classing `QWidget` or `QMainWindow`. It will give better controllability.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget, QGridLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Who wants to be a programmer?")
window.setFixedWidth(1000)

b11=QPushButton(window)

class w2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget,self).__init__()
        self.b1=QPushButton(self)

        
w_2=w2()
w_2.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```